# Getting non-singleton cluster ids in scipy hierachical clustering

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

According to Scipy [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram) we can get cluster ids for non-singleton clusters. I asked the same question on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971156/how-to-get-non-singleton-cluster-ids-in-scipy-hierachical-clustering) once.  But this doesn't seem to be the best solution and I tried several. Still I couldn't get the cluster ids for non-singletons.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

mat = np.array([[ 0. , 1. , 3.  ,0. ,2.  ,3.  ,1.],
 [ 1. , 0. , 3. , 1.,  1. , 2. , 2.],
 [ 3.,  3. , 0.,  3. , 3.,  3. , 4.],
 [ 0. , 1. , 3.,  0. , 2. , 3.,  1.],
 [ 2. , 1.,  3. , 2.,  0. , 1.,  3.],
 [ 3. , 2.,  3. , 3. , 1. , 0. , 3.],
 [ 0. , 2.,  4. , 1. , 3.,  3. , 0.],
 [ 1. , 2.,  5. , 1. , 3.,  1. , 0.],
 [ 4. , 2.,  4. , 1. , 3.,  0. , 0.],
 [ 1. , 2.,  2. , 1. , 0.,  3. , 0.]])

n = len(mat)


linkage_matrix = linkage(mat, "complete")



D = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
              p=4,
              color_threshold=1,
              truncate_mode='lastp',
              distance_sort='ascending')

plt.show()
```

Simply how to know who are inside (5),(2) and (2)? This is a very simple diagram, but this becomes more complex with lot of non-singleton clusters.

[image]

Comment: @CT Zhu : Yes, That was asked by me, which I have mentioned in this question also.

Comment: Don't mean to give you a hard time, but I am quite sure the preferred the way here is for you to edit the original question, with you additional questions/clarifications.

Comment: @CT Zhu: I have wasted lot of time on this and I thought to put this as a new question. Thanks for your advice.